# Recursive function descending output

Tags: c

```
void prikaz(int k, int n)
{
    printf("%d\t",k);

    if(k<n) 
        prikaz(k+1,n);

    printf("%d\t",k);
} 
prikaz(2,6);
```

I cant wrap my head around the output of this recursive loop, i can follow through till numbers start to descend but i dont understand why they descend.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Functions names should ideally be verbs, and in english language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the last line in the function, which prints the value of `k` after the recursive call has returned/finished. This will print the value as it was *before* the `+1`, i.e. the original value before the call.

However, it only does that part after all the recursive calls are complete.

Basically, when `k<n` is no longer true, then it will start to do the last `printf` call, then return to the previous function call and do that ones last `printf` (which will be the value of `k` before it was incremented) and it will repeat until all previous calls are complete.

It's quite hard to explain, you just need to step through it more carefully. Using a debugger would help greatly.

Maybe this helps explain it better:

```
// call 1 (k = 2)
// call 1 print 2
    // call 2 (k = 3)
    // call 2 print 3
        // call 3 (k = 4)
        // call 3 print 4
            // call 4 (k = 5)
            // call 4 print 5
                // call 5 (k = 6)
                // call 5 print 6
                    // k<n is false, so no more recursive calls.
                // call 5 print 6
            // call 4 print 5
        // call 3 print 4
    // call 2 print 3
// call 1 print 2
```